# Linked list shows segmentation fault error

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I'm pretty new to C and pointers. 
 
Following codes are for implementing a linked list in which each node contains a data of record.

However, when I compile and run this program, it shows an error "segmentation fault", and I guess the following part from my code makes an error. 
`head->next = NULL` in functions in list.c 
 
I doubt the segmentation fault error happens due to dereferencing a null pointer but have no idea what's wrong with my code.


list.h

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H
#include <stddef.h>
#include "record.h"

typedef struct node node;

struct node {         
  record  data;           
  node   *next;             
};

typedef node *record_list;  /* a record list is represented by its "head"
                               pointer */

void list_init(record_list *plist);

int list_insert(record_list *plist, const record *prec);

void list_clear(record_list *plist);

void list_print(const record_list *plist);
#endif
```

io.h

```
#ifndef IO_H
#define IO_H
#include "record.h"

void print_record(const record *p);

int read_record(record *p);

/* reads a string from stdin */
int get_word(const char prompt[], char word[]);

/* reads an int from stdin */
int get_int(const char prompt[], int *p);
#endif
```

record.h

```
#ifndef RECORD_H
#define RECORD_H

#define IDSIZE    10
#define NAMESIZE  20

typedef struct {          
  char   last[NAMESIZE];   
  char   first[NAMESIZE];  
} name;

typedef struct {   
  char  id[IDSIZE]; 
  name  name;      
  int   score;  
} record;
#endif
```

list.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "record.h"
#include "list.h"
#include "io.h"

/* initializes a record list (specified via plist) to an empty list */
void list_init(record_list *plist) {
  node *head;
  head = *plist;
  head = NULL;
  head->next = NULL;
  printf("%s", "segmentation???\n");
}

/*
 * inserts a record (specified via prec) into a record list
 */
int list_insert(record_list *plist, const record *prec) {
  node *current, *temp;
  printf("%s", "list insert\n");
  current = *plist;
  while (current->next != NULL) {
    current = current->next;
  }
  temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
  if (temp == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "memory allocate failed");
    return 0;
  }
  current->next = temp;
  current->next->data = *prec;
  current->next->next = NULL;

  printf("%s", "list insert done\n");
  return 1;
}

/*
 * deallocates all dynamic memory associated with a record list (specified
 * via plist) & resets the record list to an empty list
 */
void list_clear(record_list *plist) {
  printf("%s", "list clear\n");
  free((*plist)->next);
  plist = NULL;
  (*plist)->next = NULL;
}

/* prints all records in a record list (specified via plist) */
void list_print(const record_list *plist) {
  node *current;
  current = *plist;
  printf("%s", "list print\n");
  while (current->next != NULL) {
    print_record(&(current->data));
    current = current->next;
  }
}
```

io.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "record.h"
#include "io.h"
#define LINESIZE 1024

/*
 * prints a record (specified via p);
 */
void print_record(const record *p) {
  printf("%d %s %s %s\n", p->score, p->name.last, p->name.first, p->id);
}

/*
 * reads a record from stadard input & stores it via p;
 */
int read_record(record *p) {
  return (
        get_word("Enter id: ", p->id)
    &&  get_word("Enter last name: ", p->name.last)
    &&  get_word("Enter first name: ", p->name.first)
    &&  get_int("Enter score: ", &(p->score))
  );
}

/* reads a string from stdin */
int get_word(const char prompt[], char word[]){
  char line[LINESIZE];
  char temp[LINESIZE];
  while (1) {
    printf("%s", prompt);
    if(!fgets(line, LINESIZE, stdin)){
      clearerr(stdin);
      return 0;
    }
    if (sscanf(line, "%s", temp) == 1){
      strcpy(word, temp);
      return 1;
    }
  }
}

/* reads an int from stdin */
int get_int(const char prompt[], int *p) {
  char line[LINESIZE];
  while (1) {
    printf("%s", prompt);
    if (!fgets(line, LINESIZE, stdin)) {
      clearerr(stdin);
      return 0;
    }
    if (sscanf(line, "%d", p) == 1) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      printf("%s", "Error: The input is not given in integer.\n");
    }
  }
}
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "record.h"
#include "list.h"
#include "io.h"


int main(void) {
  record_list  list;
  record       r;

  printf("address of list: %ld\n", &list);
  printf("address of list: %ld\n", &(list->next));
  list_init(&list);

  while (read_record(&r)) {
    printf("%s\n", "read success");
    if (!list_insert(&list, &r))
      break;
  }

  list_print(&list);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you run this under a debugger (e.g. `gdb`). Compile with `-g`. Then do: `gdb ./myprogram`. Then type `run`. `gdb` will trap the segfault. You can then type `bt` to get a stack traceback and you'll see the line of code that got the fault. Also look at the `frame` in gdb. You can also single-step the program with `s`

Comment: "I doubt the segmentation fault error happens due to dereferencing a null pointer". You don't need to doubt or guess. Debug the code. Use a debugger or even basic debug print statements to trace the program execution. The debugger can tell you exactly which line of code seg faults and what the variable values are. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Ok. I'll try debugging with gdb and later update my status:)

Comment: Oh my goodness I didn't know that there's such a convenient debugger for C. Btw, it says "Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault". And the error is on `while (current->next != NULL)` in `list_insert()` function.

Comment: It might be helpful [to us and _you_] to post _all_ your code as a _single_ code block. You can insert the [missing] `.h` files at the top. This way, we can download the single file, compile it [what you post should compile _cleanly_], and run it [possibly using `gdb` on it]. In your particular case, it shouldn't be too much [more] code.

Comment: Regarding your segfault in `list_insert` [I wondered about this after a cursory look before], what would happen if the list passed was _empty_? That is, you're _not_ checking to see if `current` is non-null _before_ you dereference it in: `while (current->next != NULL) current = current->next;` In order words, Tommimon is probably right.

Comment: `list_init` has a bug. You do: `head = NULL; head->next = NULL;` So, you set `head` to a null and then _immediately_ dereference it. Remove the `head->next = NULL;` Also, the [any] value you set `head` to is lost when the function returns. And caller's list is _not_ initialized to anything. Caller's value will be random/garbage even after the call. You should probably do: `*plist = NULL;` and fix `list_insert` to handle the [resulting] null pointer.

Comment: Thanks @Craig for your kind reply! It took me a while to understand yours and Tommimon 's solution and go back and work on it. Very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to create an empty list and `plist` is the pointer to the head of the list you have to set the variable pointed by `plist` to NULL with `*plist = NULL;` , you can get rid of the code is causing the segmentation fault

Ok I think I find the next error:

```
current = *plist;
while (current->next != NULL) {
    current = current->next;
}
```

Will cause errors because the first time you call list_insert you have *plist equals to NULL because the list is empty and so current->next != NULL will cause the error (current is also equals to NULL)

I suggest the following:

```
printf("%s", "list insert\n");

if (*plist == NULL) {
    temp = (node * )malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (temp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "memory allocate failed");
        return 0;
    }
    plist = temp;
    (*plist) ->data = *prec;
    (*plist) ->next = NULL;
    return 1;
}

current = *plist;
while (current->next != NULL) {
    current = current->next;
}
```

And the rest of the code as it was, I added an if for the case *pilist is equals to NULL, in that case temp is going to point at the first element and has to be assigned to plist

Comment: I tried that before but it still causes the segmentation fault.

Comment: wait, so actually I deleted the code causing the error and put `*plist = NULL` as you said, but now it's causing error in my `list_insert()` function. I think there's something wrong with accessing to `current->next`.

Comment: Thanks @Tommimon! Your solution resolved segmentation fault problem. Thanks for your kind reply:)

Comment: Please I suggest you read carefully the section [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) If you don’t know how it works